# How to use variadic macros?

Tags: c++, macros

I am trying to use variadic macros. I want PRINTF macro to be called from MY_TOP_PRINTF macro.

1.Either I am getting compilation error.

2.If I remove compilation error, it is only printing 1st argument.

My expected result is `Inside TOP_PRINT dog here 4`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;


#define PRINTF(str, ...)  {                             \
    fprintf(stderr, (str), ##__VA_ARGS__);              \
}


#define MY_TOP_PRINTF(EXPRESSION, ...) {                \
    PRINTF("Inside TOP_PRINT ", EXPRESSION, __VA_ARGS__);\
}


int main()
{
    int x = 4;
    char str[255] = "dog here";

    MY_TOP_PRINTF(str,x);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Error:

```
hello_temp.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
hello_temp.cpp:8:41: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
     fprintf(stderr, (str), ##__VA_ARGS__);  \
                                         ^
hello_temp.cpp:13:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘PRINTF’
     PRINTF("Inside TOP_PRINT", EXPRESSION, __VA_ARGS__);\
     ^
hello_temp.cpp:23:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘MY_TOP_PRINTF’
  MY_TOP_PRINTF(str,x);
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: updated the expected result

Comment: You need to remove `##` in front of `__VA_ARGS__`. But why are you using a variadic MACRO in C++ instead of using a variadic FUNCTION or variadic TEMPLATE instead?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Why does OP need to remove ##? Says [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) is it still supported for backward compatibility

Comment: @KillzoneKid perhaps, but as you can see in other examples on that same page, it is not needed, either.